# Android: How do I open a URL in local css file

Tags: android, css, url, webview

I have a local css file that I load into a WebView, which shows with no issues.  It is a contact screen so it has a phone number, email address and a website.  When I click on the phone number or email address the phone opens the dialer or email app (respectively) with no issue, but I cannot open the URL for the website.  I have included my webView settings and my css file below

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

webView.loadUrl("file://" + htmlManager.htmlFilePath(HtmlManager.kHtmlFilenameContactUs));
```

CSS

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Phone:</td>
                        <td>123.456.7890</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email:</td>
                        <td><a href="mailto:customerservice@abc.com" target="_blank">customerservice@abc.com</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Website:</td>
                        <td><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">www.google.com</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should extend your `WebViewClient` something like this

```
public static class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
            MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { mt.getTo() });
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mt.getSubject());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, mt.getCc());
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mt.getBody());
            mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
            return true;
        } else if (url.startsWith("http://")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

And don't forget to set your client to the `WebView`

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient ());
```

**EDIT:** I just noticed that URI contains attribute target="_blank". Than you should either

```
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

or do dirty hack and remove target="_blank" with javascript like this

```
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ /*code that removes attribute*/ })()");
```

depending if you want open URL in new browser window, or load url in your `WebView`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I implemented the code, but the url still won't load.  I ran the debugger, and when I click on the mailto: the webViewClient is calling the correct code, but it doesn't call anything when I click on the url.  I get the following log when I do click on the link
<br/>
05-23 10:10:51.802: V/webview(17551):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
<br/>05-23 10:10:52.122: D/webview(17551):  blockWebkitViewMessage= false

Comment: Sorry I am new to StackOverflow and haven't figured out how to format my question/comments yet